# iOS: HTML5 video, continuous playback while remaining in fullscreen

Tags: ios, ipad, html, html5-video

I am currently developing an iPad app that aggregates various video feeds on the internet. Then using a UIWebView, some Javascript, a <video> tag, and the mp4 URL I can playback the video and the native iOS video controls appear. This all works great.

Additionally by subscribing to the video 'end' event, I can queue up another video to play after the one you were watching finishes. This also works great, *EXCEPT* if you were in fullscreen when the next video starts to play, you are taken out of it and back to the app!

Does anyone know a way that I can persist fullscreen HTML5 video in iOS when a new video is loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following worked for me on mobile safari on an iPod touch.  Listen for the end event and change the source of the current video tag to the new video.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <video id="myVideo" src="http://shapeshed.com/examples/HTML5-video-element/video/320x240.m4v" autoplay>
       </video>
       <script>
       document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
       function myHandler(e) {
           if(!e) { e = window.event; }
              // What you want to do after the event         
              document.getElementById('myVideo').src='http://movies.apple.com/media/us/html5/showcase/2010/demos/apple-html5-demo-tron_legacy-us-20100601_r848-2cie.mov';
       }
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wish I could preload/buffer the following video =)